# How to add internal Consol/terminal in Kdevelop in ubunut?

Tags: terminal, console, kdevelop

I am using KDevelop version 5.4.2 in Ubunut 18.04. I want to use internal terminal, But there is no option of that.
In **window-> Tool view**, there is no option of terminal/ console

How can i add terminal in KDevelop along side with `Code Browser` and `Build` Windows at bottom of KDevelop layout.

Comment: Do you have "Konsole Integration" plugin listed in "Settings -> Configure KDevelop -> Plugins"?

Comment: Yes, bu previously it is unmarked, We mark it, Now its working.thank you